# Javascript for ... in loop with Object.prototype and Array.prototype properties

Tags: javascript

I am reading [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for better understanding javascript. This is an excerpt from there

```js
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {}; 
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];
iterable.foo = 'hello';

for (let i in iterable) {
  console.log(i); // logs 0, 1, 2, "foo", "arrCustom", "objCustom"
}
```

In the worst case i thought it is going to print `0, 1, 2, "foo", "arrCustom"` but it also prints `objCustom`.

**Update:**
**1)**  How can i visualize the prototype chain from `iterable` to `Array` all the way upto `Object`. Like is there any `iterable.getParent` method or `iterable.myparent` property which points to parent on it.
**2)** why it does not print array functions such as `toString`, `sort` they are also on `Array.prototype`.
**3)** Do i need to use `hasOwnProperty` always when someone add something to `Array.prototype` property.

Comment: `Array` inherits from `Object`?

Comment: Thanks for comment, how does it go from `variable iterable` all the way upto `Object`, that's what i want to know more with code.

Comment: for in iterates over all enumerable properties of an object, since you did not define the properties as being non-enumerable they will be iterated over

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first question. What do you mean by "*How can i see connection*"? `iterable instanceof Array`/`iterable instanceof Object` will show that they inherit from these. If you don't know what an object inherit from but want to find out, use `Object.getPrototypeOf(iterable)`.

Comment: @Bergi updated the question

Comment: @Srinivas Ah, thanks. As I said, `Object.getPrototypeOf` can be used for that. See also the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Bergi Is there any way to go from bottom to up, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(iterable)` gives me `[]` i dont know what to do next? this time i need spoon feeding.

Comment: @Srinivas Continue to call `Object.getPrototypeOf` on that until you reach `null` (the end of the chain). See the third duplicate for example code.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for supportive information, can i make my `arrCustom`, `objCustom` non-enumerable?

Comment: @Srinivas Yes. See the first duplicate for how to do that.

Comment: Can you add one answer with proper explanation to address all these questions.

Comment: @Srinivas: I answered all of your questions below. Is there something lacking?

Comment: @Srinivas Nice Question, I had same doubts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a `for in` loop is meant to iterate all enumerable properties, both owned and inherited. You can use `Object.keys()` to get only owned properties.

```js
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {}; 
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];
iterable.foo = 'hello';

Object.keys(iterable).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key); // logs 0, 1, 2, "foo"
});
```

However, it's pretty unusual to put non-numeric properties on an `Array`. There are usually better ways to accomplish whatever it is you need to do.

It's also unusual to use a `for in` loop on an Array. There are other, better ways of iterating an Array, as long as you keep it limited to its numeric indices.

---

> 1) *"How can i visualize the prototype chain from iterable to Array all the way upto `Object`. Like is there any iterable.getParent method or iterable.myparent property which points to parent on it."*

You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to get the next object an object inherits from. Do it in a loop to go until `null` is reached.

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj);
do {
  console.log(proto);
} while((proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)));
```

> 2) *"why it does not print array functions such as `toString`, sort they are also on `Array.prototype`."*

`toString()` and other built in methods are *non-enumerable*. As I noted above, `for in` only reaches *enumerable* properties.

> 3) *"Do i need to use `hasOwnProperty` always when someone add something to `Array.prototype` property."*

Don't use `for in` loops on Arrays, and you'll do better. But yes,  if you use `for in`, you'll need `.hasOwnProperty()` boilerplate code to guard against that.

You should also be aware that there's no guarantee that Array indices will be reached in order when using `for in`. And it's also usually much slower that other means of Array iteration. It's especially slow with the `.hasOwnProperty()` check.

Comment: Thanks for answering all the question, it helped me a lot. Can I ask from where have you learned all this, Can you point me to a decent source.

Answer (score 4):

Because `for-in` iterates through all the properties of the object, including the ones inherited from the prototype. To skip the inherited properties, use `hasOwnProperty()`.

```js
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {};
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];
iterable.foo = 'hello';

for (let i in iterable) {
  if (iterable.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for..in` loops through all the properties that an object has, this means own properties and inherited. That is why `for..in` is ussually accompanied by `hasOwnProperty`, like this

```js
Object.prototype.objCustom = function() {}; 
Array.prototype.arrCustom = function() {};

let iterable = [3, 5, 7];
iterable.foo = 'hello';

for (let i in iterable) {
  if (iterable.hasOwnProperty(i))
    console.log('own', i); // logs 0, 1, 2, "foo"
  else
    console.log('not', i); // logs "arrCustom", "objCustom" (inherited)
}
```